# Javascript variable's "Value" property does not come up on the Intellisense

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Trying to get the selected value of a dropdownlist in an updatepanel, assign the value to the variable called hiddenInput. The problem is on the final line below. Once I type hiddenInput and press ".", intellisense doesn't list the property "Value". Closest one is "ValueOf". Same for the variable "address" as well. How can I assign sth into a variable's value?

```
function clientIDYakala() {
         var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("HiddenField1");
         var address = document.getElementById('cphContent_rpAdress_lblCity_0'); 
         hiddenInput.value = address.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
hiddenInput.value = address.options[address.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense isn't perfect when it comes to javascript, I'm afraid it's a known fact and all you can do is just wait for a better version and hope they will somehow fix it... Make sure you js code works, ignore VS :)